# How do you uncheck one button when another is clicked?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5

I have three buttons for aligning font in a Rich Text Box. Currently, each button, when clicked, is "checked" (it displays a blue border around the icon). Is there a way that when one of the other buttons is selected it unchecks the currently checked button?

Comment: what code have you tried?

Comment: I haven't. I've tried changing the properties of the buttons, but that didn't work.

Comment: Got it working now using the if statements. I did try those earlier but obviously it wasn't done correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something along the lines of:

```
If (Button1.Checked == true)
{ 
Button2.Checked = false;
}
Else
{
Button2.Checked = true;
}
```

Iterate through all your buttons.

Comment: `Button2.Checked = !Button1.Checked;`

Answer (score 3):

For this type of behaviour you'd more likely be better off using [RadioButtons](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.aspx) and grouping them. They will automatically handle the toggling for you.